# How to set a global directive for pageEncoding in *.tag custom tags?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, jsp-tags

In JSP you can use the following:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid> <!-- 1 -->
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding> <!-- 2 -->
    </jsp-property-group>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.tag</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Is there a custom tag equivalent to set the encoding directive for all custom tags created using a *.tag file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define JSP configuration parameters in deployment descriptor but tags declared in TLD (tag library decriptor). [TLD have no encoding parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html) and [Deployment Descriptor have no such option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/web_xml.html) for `<taglib>` element that means that you cant.

Comment: Just to make it clear, am I required to add the encoding directive for each *.tag file I create using UTF-8 encoding? There is no better way to do it without repeating boilerplate code?

Comment: only with third party libs but I dont know if such exists.